# Use loadsh filter vs splice

Tags: javascript, lodash

To remove an element from an array, which method would you prefer?

```
const removeSomethingFromArray = (index) => {
    const currentSurveyQuestions = [...surveyQuestions]
    currentSurveyQuestions.splice(index, 1)
    setSurveyQuestions(currentSurveyQuestions)
}
```

or

```
const removeSomethingFromArray = (i) => {
    const questions = _.filter(survey.questions, (_, qi) => i !== qi)
    setSurveyQuestions({ ...survey, questions })
}
```

if filter, than why I don’t see more people using it? (Sorry, if this is opinionated question)

Comment: Hi, what's the purpose of this question? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: filter excludes items and returns a new array. its different than splicing.

Comment: if you care for every nanosecond of CPU time then `filter` it more prefered one. otherwise noone cares. both of these usages are readable and making exactly the same result

Comment: @DanielA.White in the above snippet I did `const currentSurveyQuestions = [...surveyQuestions]` and then splice. so basically, I am creating a copy of the array and then using splice.

Comment: @dave trying to understand which approach is better.

Comment: @HardikKhanna its like comparing apples and oranges. each has their use.

Comment: @HardikKhanna I think everybody agrees that both approaches have their use. However, I don't see the advantage of spreading the array and then splicing  compared to filtering the original array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `.splice` is the way to go because it is simpler, faster and expresses your intent better. Filter will unnecessarily iterate over the whole array, whereas splice will cleanly remove the item you want.